# How to concatenate @something inside a render function in a template

Tags: phoenix-framework

I have this function in my template:

```
<%= for {element, id} <- Enum.with_index(MyProject.PageView.Recursion.buildElements(@header_linkNumber),1) do %>
        <%= render FabricaASA.ComponentView, @header_linkType,
            button_id: "#{id}",
            button_mainStyle: @header_mainStyle
        %>
    <% end %>
```

Now I would like to concatenate, on my right side, `@header_mainStyle + id` so that from other template, for each created element, I could pass: `header_mainStyle1, header_mainStyle2,...header_mainStyleN`

Also, on the left side, where I have `button_mainStyle:` I would like to concatenate `@header_linkType + _mainStyle:` so that I could dynamically change it to, `link_mainStyle:` or `button_mainStyle:`

Up to now I wasn't able to do it properly...

Comment: String concatenation in elixir is done using `<>`. You should be able to do this either with `@header_mainStyle <> "#{id}"` or by just interpolating both things into a string: `"#{@header_mainStyle}#{id}"`.

Comment: Thanks you Frost. That's right but in my case I want to concatenate them in order to be able to pass different values from another template inside: `header_mainStyle1, header_mainStyle2,...` and now there's and error because I'm being asked for the "raw" header_mainStyle and not for the concatenated: `assign @header_1mainStyle not available in eex template.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you are doing something wrong if you need such thing. Maybe there's a simpler solution...

Anyway: since some version of Phoenix (I'm sorry I don't know which one precisely, maybe 1.0?), @-variables are stored in @conn.assigns map and you can access them by name there. In older versions, these variables were macros and this kind of magic did not work.

So you can try to put this into the controller:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  render conn, "index.html", [var1: "var1"]
end
```

and this into the page template:

```
<p>var1: <%= @var1 %></p>
<p>assigns:</p>
<%= for i <- 1..10 do %>
  <p>var<%= i %>:<p>
  <pre><%=
  varname = "var#{i}" |> String.to_atom
  inspect(@conn.assigns[varname]) %>
  </pre>
<% end %>
```

...you will see var1 to var10 bindings (screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/4b4790cjz/). But it's little bit black magic and probably wrong approach.

Comment: Thank you Miroslav. This is really black magic :) I'm probably not using the best pattern for my goal as you say.

Comment: @PauloJaneiro: if it answers your question, could you please accept it as an answer?

Comment: Done. Nevertheless, if this helps someone, I was definitely wrong with this approach and the simplest one is to pass a list/map of values defined in your calling template to the `for <-`helper.